# Восстановление подключения ZeroMQ. REQ->REP

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, zeromq

Написал клиент-серверную передачу данных с использованием ØMQ. Судя по описанию при разрыве подключения ØMQ должна сама переподключаться. Если я вручную отключаю серверную часть программы, она переподключается, если вручную отключаю сетевую карту, она переподключается. А вот если выдернуть сетевой шнур, на продолжительное время, то при подключении его обратно, клиентская часть останавливается на "Жду ответа...", серверная на "Жду клиента". Как заставить её подключиться и  при таком дисконнекте?

Код клиента:

```
    int i = 0;
    var context = new ZContext();
    using (var client = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.REQ))
    {
        client.Connect("tcp://192.168.1.13:5555");

        while (true)
        {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine("Отправляю");
            client.Send(new ZFrame(i.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine("Отправил: " + i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("Жду ответа...");
            using (ZFrame reply = client.ReceiveFrame())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Получил: " + reply.ReadString());
            }
```

Код сервера:

```
    var context = new ZContext();
    using (var responder = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.REP))
    {
        responder.Bind("tcp://*:5555");

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Жду клиента");
            using (ZFrame request = responder.ReceiveFrame())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Получено: "+ request.ReadString());
                Console.WriteLine("Отправляю ответ");
                responder.Send(new ZFrame("Success"));
            }
        }
    }
```

P.S.
Нашел более подробное описание проблемы [ТУТ](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2012/6/26/disconnects-are-good-for-you/), но разобраться с тем как её решить не могу.

Answer (score -2):

Используйте ReceiveFrame с таймаутом

Comment: Как именно это сделать? Где указать время таймаута?

Comment: На кой черт там тайм-аут-то? Что вы собрались в случае тайм-аута делать?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Причина остановки в случае отсоединения сетевого провода скорей всего в том, что ReceiveFrame блокируется. Для ее разблокирования и нужен таймаут. Я не знаю, есть ли механизм таймаута в ЗероМКю, если его нет, вам нужно сделать нечто подобное